# Elasticsearch: NodeJS MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

My customer has an existing application built on Node and MongoDB. In this app, there is a search functionality which is more complex. I want to convert it to Elasticsearch. How can I achieve it? I have installed Elasticsearch on my system  (Windows) and now I am having confusion that, do I need to put all data in Elasticsearch? No, I don't know the concept. How can I implement Elasticsearch to the current app? Is Elasticsearch a separate database like MongoDB?

Comment: ElasticSearch is a data store, but not as you appear to understand it. I'd recommend reading up on it and then asking specific questions when you have them.

Comment: Hi, I am newbie to both MongoDB and Elastic Search. My understanding is instead of using MongoDB, I need to use elastic search.

Comment: As I said, read the documentation on ElasticSearch and learn what it is. There's not really much else to suggest at this point.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Thanks.

Comment: Yes you would have to import and index documents in the elastic node/cluster. You would need a connector/ river plugin to import the data from MongoDB to your Elastic Node/Cluster. There are a bunch of articles on the web explaining the MongoDB Elastic Search integration step by step.

Comment: @JatinChaudhary.. Thanks,, Im looking for this kind of hint to start up. ur comment was a sparrk..